# Is the ARM specification just an instruction set, or more?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

Is ARM specification just an instruction set, or does it include more than that, for instance hardware implementation details?

I guess that the value of ARM Limited as a company (around 30G$) does not come only from an instruction set, even protected by patents. So what do they really own?

Comment: I think the best way to describe it, is as an ecosystem. There are many parts to it, more than just the ISA.

Comment: ARM is a separate CPU architecture. It comes with its own instruction set, hence the reason, x86 and x64 software must be recompiled in order to support it

Comment: @Bib more precisely, what does ARM owns (in terms of IP) beyond the instruction set ?

Comment: @Ramhound indeed, but it's not my point... For instance does the specification also covers the buses, how they behave, ... ?

Comment: @PierU - Yes; Just like the x86_64 architecture does, although how devices are discovered on ARM, is significantly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARM Limited provide a lot of intellectual property and related services. These include:

- The ISAs (several, 32-bit and 64-bit).
- Designs for ARM cores, at a wide range of performance and power consumption levels, for customers to use in their own chip/SoC designs.
- Licenses to modify the cores, and more expensive licenses to design your own cores.
- Designs for busses, memory controllers, GPUs, modem and baseband communication circuits, and other mobile-device infrastructure.
- Standards for booting systems, device discovery and configuration, and related matters.
- Partnership with chip foundries to help get customer designs into production quickly.
- Software development tools.
- Documentation for all of the above.
- Consultancy and support.

For example, in 2021, I was engaged in porting Linux software that already ran on x86-64 to ARM64. The objective was to run it on Amazon Cloud; Amazon design and build their own ARM processors for this service. The software already ran on several other ARM64 platforms, so there were no fundamental problems with the porting.

We were based in Cambridge, UK, so co-operation with ARM Ltd was easy. They provided valuable advice on selection of an appropriate Linux distribution and GCC version for building and testing software, and assisted us with getting ARM servers running in our own datacentre. This made the job quicker and easier.

The thing ARM don't sell is manufactured chips in bulk. They do sell evaluation and/or development boards, sometimes, but SoC manufacturers, like Qualcomm, are more active in that business.